# I can't load image using absolute path in Xamarin?

Tags: xamarin

I need to load an image from my special folder not Assets folder of my project.
My code is

```
Image img = new Image();
img.Source = ImageSource.FromFile("c:\\file.png");
```

But I can't show anything.
How can I do?

Comment: imgPic.Source = ImageSource.FromFile("C:\\Users\\TEMP\\AppData\\Local\\Packages\\b606de12-4f15-4da3-afef-4dbbe56a99f7_ysn4p81cqstf4\\LocalState\\speedtest - Copy (3).png");

I got this url from CrossMedia.Current.PickPhotoAsync();

I can load this image but I can't load the above one.

Comment: Just think about it for a second - when you deploy your app to an iOS/Android device, how is it supposed access the c: drive on your PC?  It can't.  It can only access files that are located in it's own filesystem.  When you run an app in the simulator, a local subset of your PC's filesystem is treated as the simulator's filesystem.

Comment: I am developing an app for win 10 Phone using Xamarin Platform.
So I am testing on a Local machine mode.
If OK, then I'm gonna test on my win 10 Phone.
My project is UWP.

Comment: The same principle applies - the W10 Phone emulator does not have access to your C:\ drive.  It can only see files that are in it's own file system.    See https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/working-with/files/